# Define Ruby as the default syntax highlighting scheme for Rspec

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

I stumbled into this [question which contains a block of Ruby code with test specs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292061/testing-rest-api-responses-with-rspec-and-racktest). It seems as if the syntax highlighting does not work. Here is a screenshot in case it looks different on your browser.

[image: Question using Ruby RSpec code]

As suggested by Mat it would be nice to have the RSpec being rendered with the same scheme used for Ruby.

Comment: Fixed the post. The question doesn't have a ruby tag, so the language wasn't inferred. You should change this Q to a [feature-request] to have the [rspec] tag use ruby syntax highlighting if that's necessary... which I'm not sure about. Most should also have a ruby tag, shouldn't they?

Comment: Ah. I did not know that tags are considered when the syntax highlighting decision machine inspects the code.